# have a file "httpd-access.txt" and i want to count the number of times a line starts with '81' in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
numberOfTime = 0
with open('httpd-access.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        finded = line.find('81')
        if finded != -1 and finded != 0:
            numberOfTime += 1
```

How can i do for just to count the number of times a line starts with `81`. 
Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startswith()` for this:

```
numberOfTime = 0
with open('httpd-access.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('81'):
            numberOfTime += 1
```

Here a function to achieve what you need:

```
def count_lines(httpd_file):
    counter = 0
    with open(httpd_file) as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            if line.startswith('81'):
                counter += 1

    return counter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(count_lines('httpd-access.txt'))
```